# Locking out user from Android application

Tags: android

I'm looking in to the capability of locking out a user from using my application further. Let's say your app will run for some time, and after some event (time expiration, # of app starts, etc.), you want to lock out the application, or brick the app in some way that it can't be used anymore

I've considered storing a piece of data either as an internal file, or as a shared preference value, that would track when the event is hit. The issue here I believe is that the user can go in to the OS and simpy clear the data, which would erase the progression to the lockout event.

Does the community have any suggestions of being able to lock out a user that can't be circumenvented, and doesn't require a rooted phone / unique ROM image? I am targeting Android 4.0+ if necessary, but currently have min SDK of 11, and target SDK of 15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this in an early beta by checking the date, then after the specific date, displaying a message saying it had expired and doing a divide by 0 error.

For a specific time after they have installed it, you will have to use an online service, or try and hide a file on the SD card (not guranteed to work at all).